# Javascript - how to look for mismatch in the loop?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to find if there is any mismatch from the user input against the existing data then do something:

```
var reset = false;    
var user = [ 
  { public_name: 'e', code_name: 'f' },
  { public_name: 'c', code_name: 'not match' },
  { public_name: 'a', code_name: 'b' } 
];

var server = [
   {"code_name":"b","public_name":"a"},
   {"code_name":"d","public_name":"c"},
   {"code_name":"f","public_name":"e"}
]

user.forEach(function(field, index) {
   var matchingSpecies = server.find(function(item) {
       if (item.code_name === field.code_name 
           && item.public_name === field.public_name) {
           // matched so do nothing
       } else {
           // not match and stop looping
           reset = true;
       }
    });
});

console.log(reset);
```

but the result I get is always `true` even though there is a match.

any ideas?

Comment: It might be because, you are iterating through all the elements in the `user` array. So, even if any one of them does not match, `reset` is set to `true`.

Comment: why don't you try filtering those that do not match and check whether there are any. If it does, than you assign true to reset?

Comment: @n0m4d how do i use the filter?

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt your code like this:

```
var reset = false;    
var user = [ 
  { public_name: 'e', code_name: 'f' },
  { public_name: 'c', code_name: 'not match' },
  { public_name: 'a', code_name: 'b' } 
];

var server = [
   {"code_name":"b","public_name":"a"},
   {"code_name":"d","public_name":"c"},
   {"code_name":"f","public_name":"e"}
]

user.forEach(function(field, index) {
   var match = false;
   server.find(function(item) {
       if (item.code_name === field.code_name 
           && item.public_name === field.public_name) {
           match = true;
       }
    });
    reset = reset || ! match;
});

console.log(reset);
```

Comment: thanks. but the user sometimes has this `{ public_name: 'c', code_name: 'not match' },`

Comment: Update `reset = reset || ! match;` to `reset = ! match || reset;`

Comment: @teelou when the item has "not match" than it should assign true to reset?

Comment: @n0m4d yes. when there is a mismatch then reset.

Comment: @teelou It seems that my code works even when there is a `"not match"` codename.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Note: I have made a copy of original `user` and updated it to match `server` to show both states.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40mv47ux/1/)

```js
function findMatching(array) {
  var _reset = false;
  array.forEach(function(field, index) {
    var matchingSpecies = server.find(function(item) {
      return item.code_name !== field.code_name && item.public_name === field.public_name
    });
    _reset = matchingSpecies && Object.getOwnPropertyNames(matchingSpecies).length>0 || _reset
  });
  return _reset;
}

var user=[{public_name:"e",code_name:"f"},{public_name:"c",code_name:"not matched"},{public_name:"a",code_name:"b"}],
    user1=[{public_name:"e",code_name:"f"},{public_name:"c",code_name:"d"},{public_name:"a",code_name:"b"}],
    server=[{code_name:"b",public_name:"a"},{code_name:"d",public_name:"c"},{code_name:"f",public_name:"e"}];

console.log(findMatching(user));
console.log(findMatching(user1));
```